# com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events does not contain SQSEvent

Tags: eclipse, amazon-web-services

I am trying to create a Lambda function in eclipse to read off a queue in AWS.

The sample for creating a Lambda function talking to SQS contains:

```
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.SQSEvent;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.SQSEvent.SQSMessage;
```

However my `com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events` does not contain `SQSEvent`:

How do I add that? Am I missing something?

The sample to read a queue in AWS is:

```
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.SQSEvent;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.SQSEvent.SQSMessage;

public class ProcessSQSEvents implements RequestHandler<SQSEvent, Void>{
    @Override
    public Void handleRequest(SQSEvent event, Context context)
    {
        for(SQSMessage msg : event.getRecords()){<br>
            System.out.println(new String(msg.getSQS().getBody()));
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

But I canot find the SQSEvent in the:

```
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.
```

I only get:

```
.CognitoEvent
.ConfigEvent
.DynamodbEvent
.KinesisEvent
.S3Event
.SNSEvent
```

I have tried reinstalling both eclipse and the AWS SDK.

Comment: We need to see some of your code to understand the problem.

Comment: Hi, I'm having the same problem and I'm using the latest aws-lambda-java-events jar (3.11.0). Did you figure out a solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It might be the case that you are using lower version of aws-lambda-java-events jar. 
Use 2.2.2 version and you will have no issues